# as3 how to remove graphics from removed nape bodies

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, for-loop, reset

i have attached multiple instances of a moviecCip to multiple nape bodies and have a reset button to restore them to their original position. when the reset function is called the bodies are reset and have the mc attached to them. the problem is the original mc are still on the stage frozen in the position thy were when reset was called.

```
private var brickGraphic:MovieClip = new Brick();
private var brickArray:Array;

private function setUp():void
{
    var brickType:CbType = new CbType();
    var w:int = stage.stageWidth;
var h:int = stage.stageHeight;
var ag:int = stage.stageHeight - 58;// height ofarea above ground
    brickArray = new Array  ;

    //wall
    for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++)
    { 
    var brick:Body = new Body(BodyType.DYNAMIC);
    var brickShape:Polygon = new Polygon(Polygon.box(10,25));
    var brickGraphic:MovieClip = new Brick();
    brickGraphic.width = 10;
    brickGraphic.height = 25;
    addChild(brickGraphic);
    brickGraphic.cacheAsBitmap = true;
    brick.shapes.add(brickShape);
    brick.position.setxy(450, ((ag ) - 30 * (i + 0.5)));
    brick.angularVel = 0;
    brick.shapes.at(0).material.elasticity = .5;
    brick.shapes.at(0).material.density = 150;
    brick.cbTypes.add(brickType);
    brick.space = space;
    brickGraphic.stop();

    brick.userData.sprite = brickGraphic;
    brick.userData.sprite.x = brick.position.x;
    brick.userData.sprite.y = brick.position.y;

    this.brickArray.push(brick);
    }
}

private function reset():void
{
    space.clear();
    setUp();
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Add a statement that will remove that linked MovieClip from those nape bodies into your `reset()` function. I expect this is what you need:

```
private function reset():void
{
    if (contains(brick.userData.sprite)) removeChild(brick.userData.sprite);
    space.clear();
    setUp();
}
```

Comment: that returns the following error `code`TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: This means there is not enough code in here. You need to find the place where you detach either `brick` or `brick.userData`, so that the reference to `brickGraphic` that you create in `setUp()` will be accessible, and there remove the old and to-be-dropped movie clip.

Comment: do you mean declare `private var brickGraphic:MovieClip = new Brick();` outside the setup function because when i tried that it only attaches one graphic

Comment: This will also do. We just need a link that'll be removed from your brick to be available at `reset()`. An alternative is to reuse that brick graphics.

Comment: Making `brickGraphic` a class-wide variable, and using it in `reset()` to remove existing graphic, then in `setup()` to add new graphic.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27103/discussion-between-lonergan6275-and-vesper)

Comment: yes but as i said that only attaches the mc to one of the bodies. could you please edit your answer to help explain